# Kernel panic not syncing : System is deadlocked on memory

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, compiling

I updated my Ubuntu 14.04 kernel to 4.19, however,when I reboot there's a error: `Kernel panic - not syncing: System is deadlocked on memory`.
It remains there, and I don't know what to do.

[image]

1. I have made my kernel several times and installed the modules,there's no error show in the old terminal.
2. I used GParted to enlarge my dev/sda1,and I have set the Swap area, all done.
3. Everything is pretty well about the old kernel. I can login and use smoothly.

Comment: How did you upgrade the kernel? Also, why did you want to use the newer kernel? Any problem with just using the stock one? There might be an easier way to get the feature(s) you need from the newer kernel.

Comment: I installed a new one linux-4.19,I reboot and want to use the new one because I added a syscall in linux-4.19...actually,this is my homework and I have to make it right...

Comment: yeah but *how* did you install it? what process did you follow? It seems like you did something wrong in the configuration, but we can't see what it was since you haven't given any info... A [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) means processes are waiting for each other so that none of them can start...

Comment: Command I have used:`#cp /boot/config-**** .config; # make menuconfig;#make -j4;#make modules_install ;#make install;#reboot`;As for the syscall,I just add a very simple helloword in the sys.c and I have added it in the syscalls.h and syscall_64.tbl. Everything works well in the old one...I really don't know.

Comment: well what do you do in `make menuconfig` :) ? Really you are not giving enough information for anyone to help you! I would expect to see in your question (not in the comments) every command you have run and any warnings from `make` (`tee` out to a file if you don't want to sit and watch it). Does this kernel build and boot without you adding your patch and whatever you do in `make menuconfig`? The vanilla kernel (if that's what you're building - you haven't said!) will be very light on drivers compared to the Ubuntu kernel, might not have everything for your device. Also why compile as root?

Comment: BTW, most of the kernel experts are probably on [unix.se]. Your question is fine and on-topic here, but you can delete it and ask it there instead if you want and you might be more likely to get more helpful comments than mine haha

Comment: I didn't change anything in 'make menuconfig' , just choose 'save' there...*_*

Comment: I really appreciate that you show me Unix & Linux...this is my first time using StackExchange...@_@, I'm going 2 move my question 2 Unix & Linux.Thank U very much.